# I want to set value in the HTTP request and fetch the value in another independent MVVM related to a different zul file

Tags: java, data-binding, mvvm, zk

I am studying ZK framework for quite some time. I have not been able to figure out how to set parameters in HTTP request and fetch them in some other page?

I have also not been able to use `@GlobalCommand` annotation. How this `@GlobalCommand` works actually?

I dont want to send values to a popup or a modal dialog. I want to send values to independent zul page through sendRedirect etc...

Please provide examples for these two things.

Example I have made for `@GlobalCommand`

DemoVM.java

```
package com.nagarro.viewmodel;

import java.util.HashMap;
import org.zkoss.bind.BindUtils;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.BindingParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.GlobalCommand;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.NotifyChange;

public class DemoVM {

    private String value1;
    private String value2;

    @Command
    public void showModelWin() {
        final HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("value1", this.value1);
        map.put("value2", this.value2);
        BindUtils.postGlobalCommand(null, null, "getValues", map);
        Executions.sendRedirect("ModelWindow.zul");
    }

    @GlobalCommand
    @NotifyChange({ "value1", "value2" })
    public void refreshvalues(@BindingParam("returnvalue1") String str1,
            @BindingParam("returnvalue2") String str2) {
        this.value1 = str1;
        this.value2 = str2;
    }

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

Demo.zul

```
<?page title="Demo Page" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>
    <window title="MVVM Modal window Passing arguments and return values"
        border="normal" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" id="DemoVM"
        viewModel="@id('e') @init('com.nagarro.viewmodel.DemoVM')">
        Type any value and Press the Model Window Button
        <separator />
        Value 1 :
        <textbox value="@bind(e.value1)" />
        Value 2 :
        <textbox value="@bind(e.value2)" />
        <button label="Model Window" onClick=" @command('showModelWin')" />
    </window>
</zk>
```

ModelWindowVM.java

```
package com.nagarro.viewmodel;

import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.BindingParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextType;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ExecutionArgParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.GlobalCommand;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Init;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.NotifyChange;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.zkoss.bind.BindUtils;
import java.util.Map;

public class ModelWindowVM {

    private String value1;
    private String value2;



    @Init
    public void init(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view,
            @ExecutionArgParam("value1") String v1,
            @ExecutionArgParam("value2") String v2) {
        this.value1 = v1;
        this.value2 = v2;
    }


    @Command
    public void save() {
        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        args.put("returnvalue1", this.value1);
        args.put("returnvalue2", this.value2);
        BindUtils.postGlobalCommand(null, null, "refreshvalues", args);
        Executions.sendRedirect("Demo.zul");
    }

    @GlobalCommand("getValues")
    @NotifyChange({"value1","value2"})
    public void getValues(@BindingParam("value1") String value1, @BindingParam("value2") String value2){
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;

    }
    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

}
```

ModelWindow.zul

```
<?page title="Model Window Page" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>

    <window id="modalDialog"
        title="MVVM Modal window Passing arguments and retur values"
        width="420px" height="auto" border="normal" minimizable="false"
         maximizable="false" closable="true"
        action="hide: slideUp" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        onCancel="@command('closeThis')"
        viewModel="@id('e') @init('com.nagarro.viewmodel.ModelWindowVM')">

        Change the values and Press the Ok Button to return changed
        values.
        <separator />
        Value 1 :
        <textbox value="@bind(e.value1)" />
        Value 2 :
        <textbox value="@bind(e.value2)" />
        <button label="Ok" onClick="@command('save')" />
    </window>
</zk>
```

I have used BindUtils.postGlobalCommand() method but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by http request parameters. Maybe you want to
call the url with parameters like [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Example_of_execution_getParameter)?

You could use [`Executions.createComponents(...)`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/6.5.1/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Executions.html#createComponents%28java.lang.String,%20org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component,%20java.util.Map%29) instead of redirect,
to pass a map of data to a new page as well.
Just detach the components you do not need anymore by calling
`myComponent.setParent(null)` of the highest element in the tree you don't need
and append the new components to its fromer parent.
If you like to change the URL, you could use [HTML5-History-API](http://blog.zkoss.org/index.php/2012/03/30/history-management-with-html5-history-api-in-zk/).

A method with the `@GlobalCommand` annotation could be called by
[`postGlobalCommand(...)`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/bind/BindUtils.html#postGlobalCommand%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29)

### Edit

But you problem is, that you try to call a method with `postGlobalCommand(...)`
that does not exist at this time, because you try to call `getValues(...)`from
 ModelWindow.zul's VM instance, but there is no ModelWindow.zul open at the
client so there is no instance of `ModelWindowVM`. Notice, a VM class instance
always coexists with the component it is initialized to.

As I mentioned above, a way to solve you problem is to use `createComponents()`,
cos you can simply pass the map, that you now try pass to the global command, to `createComponents()`.

### Other ways to access data in zk

[Here](http://www.zkoss.org/forum/listComment/10366) at the bottom, is discribed how to save values to be accessable
from all *.zul, `Composer` or VM classes of the same [Desktop](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Guide/Fundamental_ZK/Basic_Concepts/Page_and_Desktop).

Or you could use server side [event queues](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Queues).

Comment: Executions.createComponents() doesnt open a new page for the file. I need to explicitly detach the existing window from the view and then only I can get an independent view of the created component. Also, the url doesn't change in this case.

Comment: I have also used BindUtils.postGlobalCommand() but its not responding.

Comment: Please provide the code of your BindUtils.postGlobalCommand() there must be something wrong. I did some edits for the createComponents() issuse.

Comment: I tried it with Executions.createComponents but in that case the first window remains opened even after I open the second window and the url remains the same as it was for the first window. I need to explicitly detach the first window by wiring it to the MVVM then only I can get the desired result. I think thts not the graceful way of doing it.

Comment: There are two way, the first is what you figered out now and I mentioned that above. There is no problem with it, cos zk is ajax and detaching old components and attach new is ajax. Of course you have to change the url by your self, but this is normal for ajax, and as I metioned above HTML5 History API is the best to do so. The secound is to [use url parameters](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Example_of_execution_getParameter), what I mentioned above as well. I would always prefer the `createComponents()` way, except for navigation, because you have more control and no data in the URL.